# Autocomplete on select event should populate input text boxes

Tags: jquery, html

**I dont see any autocomplete values**

I have an Array of object `[{"email":"marie@gmail.com","name":"marie"},{"email":"miss@gmail.com","name":"miss"}]` from the server end.

I have three input fields 1)select tag 2) input text.I want to autocomplete all the matched strings of name property in array of object in the select tag. Upon selecting the any one of the name value say for marie.The selected value should automatically fetch its email ie.,marie@gmail.com and populate into input text.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<link
    href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleAutocomplete(request) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'getAdvocate.jsp?q=' + request.term,
            dataType : "json",
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data) {
                // use 'term' for custom filtering etc.
                var options = $.grep(data, function(e) {
                    return e.name.startsWith(request);
                });
                return options;
            },
            error : function(response) {
                //alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure : function(response) {
                //alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
    $(function() {
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            minLength : 0,
            delay : 0,
            scroll : true,
            autofocus : true,
            source : function(request, response) {
                var data = handleAutocomplete(request); /* get answers from somewhere.. */
            },
            focus : function(event, ui) {
                $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
                return false;
            },

            select : function(event, ui) {
                $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
                $("#email").val(ui.item.email);
                return false;
            }
        }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
            //.append("<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.email + "</a>")
            .append("<a>" + item.name + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
</script>
<body>
    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <input id="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var users = [{
        "email": "marie@gmail.com",
        "name": "marie"
    }, {
        "email": "miss@gmail.com",
        "name": "miss"
    }];

    function handleAutocomplete(term) {
        // use 'term' for custom filtering etc.
        var options = $.grep(users, function(e) {
            return e.name.startsWith(term);
        });
        return options;
    }
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var name = request.term;
            var data = handleAutocomplete(name); /* get answers from somewhere.. */
            response(data);
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },

        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
            $("#email").html(ui.item.email);
            return false;
        }
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.email + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    $("#name").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getAdvocate.jsp?q=' + request.term,
                data: "",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                },
                error: function(response) {

                },
                failure: function(response) {

                }
            });
        },
        select: function(e, i) {

        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

**prefix matching :**

https://jsfiddle.net/duoc5bbh/1/

**any matching :**

https://jsfiddle.net/duoc5bbh/2/

Comment: Islam when i type 'm' i don't want its email i just want to have only its name in autocomplete select box.

Comment: It should start searching any where in middle of the word that matches not only first character of name.

Comment: I hope you  could manage it but still I am updating my answer so that your requirement is fulfilled :)

Comment: Please check this now. And if it works could you please accept the answer ?

Comment: I did accept. But I want to get data dynamically from ajax.Please dont take it from array.

Answer (score 0):

in your jsp page :

```
<%
   String q= request.getParameter("q");
   // then do you sql query with Like '%q%' then it will work as exactly you want  
%>
```

and return json response must be like

```
 var users = [{
    "email": "marie@gmail.com",
    "name": "marie"
}, {
    "email": "miss@gmail.com",
    "name": "miss"
}];

$(function() {

    $("#name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'getAdvocate.jsp?q=' + request.term,
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            },
            error: function(response) {

            },
            failure: function(response) {

            }
          });
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },

        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#name").val(ui.item.name);
            $("#email").html(ui.item.email);
            return false;
        }
    }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.email + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Comment: Syntax error on token ".", : expected 
at line  $.ajax({

Comment: check the changes and let me know

Comment: syntax error has gone. But when i click on character a related values are not dropping down.But request to getAdvocate.jsp is went well.